# segmenting vector with NaN´s

Tags: matlab

I have an index vector with NaN's such as:

```
index=[ 1 2 3 NaN NaN NaN 7 8 9 10 NaN 12 13 14 15 NaN NaN NaN 19 20]
```

What I want is to obtain in a cell the segments between the NaN's.

So I would want:

```
segments_index={[1 2 3 ], [ 7 8 9 10], [12 13 14 15], [19 20]};
```

How to automatically implement this operation?

Comment: Replace all non-NaN values with 0 and NaN values with 1: `m = isnan(index); index(m) = 1; index(~m) = 0;`  then use the above duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connected components is one way to do that:

```
index=[ 1 2 3 NaN NaN NaN 7 8 9 10 NaN 12 13 14 15 NaN NaN NaN 19 20];
notnan = ~isnan(index);
cc = bwconncomp(notnan);
segments_index = cellfun(@(i) index(i),cc.PixelIdxList,'UniformOutput',0)
```

Comment: many , many thanks for this code, worked fine